# Why do some African American people say "it don't..." in some movies?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, expressions

I have watched 2 movies "**The way back**" & "**Just mercy**". I noticed that some African American actors say "**it don't...**" in the movie. I could not find the scripts  of these films.

**Didn't the director correct the script?**

Or **is that a correct expression?**

Why do some African American people say "**it don't...**" in some movies?

Comment: A lot of people say "it don't" for "it doesn't" and I don't believe there is an ethnic bias. It's just the way some people talk.

Comment: @JavaLatte this question asks "why" the older question asks which form is correct. Well...in some English dialects "it don't" is grammatical* for their uses and for their community.

Comment: @Lambie: I downvoted it because it smells of trolling. If an African American actor says "it don't" when playing the part of an African American in a film, there is really nothing that needs explaining, is there?

Comment: @TonyK Right you are. I have an idea. :) Follow my lead. (It's either complete ignorance or racism.) :) You are right.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes, the older question asks which form is correct, but one of the answers explains why :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some African-Americans speak a dialect.

It is called: AAVE: African-American Vernacular English.

**BLACK LIVES MATTER**

[AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English)

Comment: "Verbs are uninflected for number and person: there is no -s ending in the present-tense third-person singular. Example: She write poetry ("She writes poetry"). AAVE don't for standard English doesn't comes from this, unlike in some other dialects which use don't for standard English doesn't but does when not in the negative. Similarly, was is used for what in standard English are contexts for both was and were.[69]"

Comment: @Tom, why tell me? Your sentence that begins "AAVE don't [etc.]" makes no sense at all.

Comment: I copied from your link

Comment: You copied badly: Verbs are uninflected for number and person: there is no -s ending in the present-tense third-person singular. Example: She write poetry ("She writes poetry"). AAVE *don't* for standard English *doesn't* comes from this, unlike in some other dialects which use *don't* for standard English *doesn't* but *does* when not in the negative. Similarly, *was* is used for what in standard English are contexts for both *was* and *were*.